# Create border around multiple UIViews

Tags: swift, uiview, border, calayer

I have a bunch of irregularly-shaped keyboards that I'd like to put separate borders around. Each key is a separate UIView and they're all contained in a wrapper Keyboard view. They look like this:

[image]

Ideally the borders should all look like the red one in the bottom left (mocked up in Preview) and have rounded corners when necessary, but I'd consider just getting the right shape a good start.

What's the best way to do this? Shapes and masks? A complex path? It seems like I'd need CALayers either way but I'm sort of new at those.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Jake

Comment: Seems like you *might* be able to get away with simply using the view hierarchy and each view's `layer.border`. I say "might" because it depends on three things: (1) Using the view hierarchy, can you set each view's `backgroundColor` to something opaque, hiding the key or view border that is beneath it? (2) Also with the view hierarchy... how are you detecting taps? But the largest one is related to `layer.cornerRadius`. (3) Only in iOS 11 can a view have two rounded corners. You can do it in earlier iOS versions, but not as simply: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/masked-and-animated-corners/

Comment: Thanks for responding! To answer your questions:

1) I'm not all that experienced with the view hierarchy, _but_ I did implement a `bringSubview(toFront)` method for each black key in my Keyboards. Each Keyboard has an array var called `keys` that contains every Key in the Keyboard. And all keyboards are in an array called `keyboards`. So I can set the background of the first key in any Keyboard, for example, by specifying `keyboards[n].keys[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.green`.

2) I set up a longpress tap gesture recognizer for each individual key, first white keys and then black keys.

Comment: 3) I can do rounded corners for iOS 11 if I'm just implementing the border around a view. I can probably figure it out for earlier iOS versions as well. I was curious though if there might be a good way to simulate rounded corners using paths and arcs or something like that.

So if I were to use the view hierarchy, how would that work? Would I need an additional view or views that I would then cover up with the keys? Or is it the other way around (or neither)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I ended up using `CAShapeLayers` and `UIBezierPaths` to draw a border around the keyboards; I used arcs to simulate rounded corners:

```
func createBezier(key1Num: Int, key2Num: Int, key3Num: Int, key4Num: Int) {
    borderPath = UIBezierPath()

    let key1 = self.keys[key1Num].frame
    let key2 = self.keys[key2Num].frame
    let key3 = self.keys[key3Num].frame
    let key4 = self.keys[key4Num].frame
    let arcRadius = key1.height * 1/32

    let start = CGPoint(x: key1.origin.x, y: key1.origin.y)

    func bothEdgeNotesBlack() {
        borderPath.move(to: start)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: key1.height * 31/32))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: start.x + arcRadius, y: key1.height * 31/32), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: leftAng, endAngle: bottomAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key2.origin.x, y: key1.height))
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key2.origin.x, y: key2.height - arcRadius))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key2.origin.x + arcRadius, y: key2.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: leftAng, endAngle: bottomAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key3.origin.x + key3.width - arcRadius, y: key2.height))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key3.origin.x + key3.width - arcRadius, y: key2.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: bottomAng, endAngle: rightAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key3.origin.x + key3.width, y: key4.height))
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: bottomAng, endAngle: rightAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width, y: key4.origin.y))
        borderPath.close()
    }

    func leftBlackrightWhite() {
        borderPath.move(to: start)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: key1.height * 31/32))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: start.x + arcRadius, y: key1.height * 31/32), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: leftAng, endAngle: bottomAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key2.origin.x, y: key1.height))
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key2.origin.x, y: key2.height - arcRadius))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key2.origin.x + arcRadius, y: key2.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: leftAng, endAngle: bottomAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: bottomAng, endAngle: rightAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width, y: key4.origin.y))
        borderPath.close()
    }

    func leftWhiteRightBlack() {
        borderPath.move(to: start)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: key1.height * 31/32))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: start.x + arcRadius, y: key1.height * 31/32), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: leftAng, endAngle: bottomAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key3.origin.x + key3.width - arcRadius, y: key3.height))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key3.origin.x + key3.width - arcRadius, y: key3.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: bottomAng, endAngle: rightAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key3.origin.x + key3.width, y: key4.height))
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: bottomAng, endAngle: rightAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width, y: key4.origin.y))
        borderPath.close()
    }

    func bothEdgeNotesWhite() {
        borderPath.move(to: start)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: key1.height * 31/32))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: start.x + arcRadius, y: key1.height * 31/32), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: leftAng, endAngle: bottomAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height))
        borderPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width - arcRadius, y: key4.height - arcRadius), radius: arcRadius, startAngle: bottomAng, endAngle: rightAng, clockwise: false)
        borderPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: key4.origin.x + key4.width, y: key4.origin.y))
        borderPath.close()
    }

    switch self.keys[key1Num].keyType {
    case 2, 5, 7, 10, 12: // 1st key is black
        switch self.keys[key4Num].keyType {
            case 2, 5, 7, 10, 12: // last key is black
            bothEdgeNotesBlack()
        case 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11:
            leftBlackrightWhite() // last key is white
        default:
            ()
        }
    case 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11: // 1st key is white
        switch self.keys[key4Num].keyType {
        case 2, 5, 7, 10, 12: // last key is black
            leftWhiteRightBlack()
        case 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11: // last key is white
            bothEdgeNotesWhite()
        default:
            ()
        }
    default:
        ()
    }
}

func borderBezier(key1Num: Int, key2Num: Int, key3Num: Int, key4Num: Int) {
    self.createBezier(key1Num: key1Num, key2Num: key2Num, key3Num: key3Num, key4Num: key4Num)

    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.zPosition = 4
    borderLayer.path = self.borderPath.cgPath

    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    self.borderLayer = borderLayer
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.borderLayer)
}
```

Image below is working code, not a mockup :-)
[image]